# Prices do not work with Layout Type Controller for Products

Tags: magento2, layout

I am trying to create a controller than I am using to load products into a page via ajax. However when i set the controller to just be of type layout the pricing no longer shows. However when using a standard page the prices show fine:

```
<?php


namespace Harrigo\ContractPricing\Controller\ContractProducts;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class AjaxProducts extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * 
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context  $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    )
    {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->_resultFactory = $context->getResultFactory();
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    /**
     * Execute view action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
            $resultLayout = $this->_resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_LAYOUT);
            return $resultLayout;   

    }
}
```

> **This however shows pricing fine:**

```
<?php
namespace Harrigo\ContractPricing\Controller\ContractProducts;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class AjaxCategory extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    protected $resultPageFactory;
    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context  $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Execute view action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        return $this->resultPageFactory->create();
    }
}
```

Both use the same block level code and templates.

Have also attempted to use controller like so:

```
<?php
namespace Harrigo\ContractPricing\Controller\ContractProducts;

class AjaxProducts extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $resultLayoutFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutFactory $layoutFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $jsonResultFactory
    ) {
        $this->layoutFactory = $layoutFactory;
        $this->jsonResultFactory = $jsonResultFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Execute view action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $productsBlockHtml = $this->layoutFactory->create()->createBlock('Harrigo\ContractPricing\Block\Index\Pricing')->setTemplate('Harrigo_ContractPricing::index/ajaxproducts.phtml')->toHtml();
        return $this->jsonResultFactory->create()->setData(['html' => [
            'products_list' => $productsBlockHtml
        ]]);
    }
}
```

However pricing just stops showing still.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the value empty to the update handle seems to fix the issue.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <update handle="empty"/>
   <container name="root" label="Root">
        <block class="Harrigo\ContractPricing\Block\Index\Pricing" name="contractproducts" template="Harrigo_ContractPricing::index/ajaxproducts.phtml" cacheable="false"></block>
    </container>
</layout>
```